# JQuery Function only works when alerting a message

Tags: jquery, xml

I have a function which I use to populate a Google map canvas with data. The function works perfectly when I click menu items and initialize it, however it doesn't work when I just run the function inside of $(document).ready. I've tried initializing it via $(document).load but had no luck either. Now the weird thing is that if I add an alert to the function at a specific line, the function initializes just fine. I also noticed that if I don't initialize it, I actually need to click one of the menu items twice before the function works for the first time. So basically, there's something up with the function's first initialization. It could have something to do with loading the XML for the first time, not sure...

Here's the function:

```
function getMap($li, $province, $zoom) {

    var $lat_array = [];
    var $long_array = [];

    $li.addClass("province-active");
    $li.siblings("li").removeClass("province-active");
    $li.css("background-image", "url(img/minus-icon-storefinder.png");
    $li.siblings("li").css("background-image", "url(img/plus-icon-storefinder.png");
    $li.siblings("li").children(".province-sub-menu").empty();
    $li.children(".province-sub-menu").empty();

    $.get('xml/map-data.xml', function(data) {$xml_text = data;}, 'text'); //If I add an alert here, the function works fine the first time
    var xml = $xml_text;
    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml );
    var $xml = $( xmlDoc );

    $province = $xml.find('province[category="' + $province + '"]');

    $(".store-locations").empty();
    $(".store-locations").append("<h3>Click on the store for more information:</h3>");

    $province.find('shop').each(function(i) {
        $suburb = $(this).find("suburb").text();
        $shop = "<div class='shop'><h4>" + $suburb + ", <span>" + $(this).find("city").text() + "</span></h4><p>" + $(this).find("tel").text() + "</p><p>" + $(this).find("fax").text() + "</p>" + "<a href=''>View store details</a></div>";

        $li.children(".province-sub-menu").append("<li data-suburb='" + $suburb + "'>" + $(this).find("suburb").text() + "," + $(this).find("city").text() + "</li>");

        $(".store-locations").append($shop);
        $lat_array[i] = $(this).find("lat").text();
        $long_array[i] = $(this).find("long").text();
     });

    initialize($lat_array, $long_array, $zoom);
}
```

Here's the initialization of the function outside of clicks:

```
var $head_office = $("#head-office");
var $province = "Head Office";
getMap($head_office, $province, 17);
```

Here's the click function:

```
$(".provinces > ul > li").click(function() {
    $li = $(this);
    $province = $li.children("p").text();   
    getMap($li, $province, 15); 
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not waiting for the GET request to complete. The code following the GET needs to be in an onsuccess handler.

By waiting for the alert to clear, you're giving it enough time to finish by accident.

Comment: Ah you see, I figured it would be something very simple. Unfortunately I'm a bit of a JQuery newbie. Thanks for the help mate, that did the trick!